# How to echo variables inside an ANSI quoted string

Tags: bash, curl, quotes

I need to execute a curl command like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopid=9932781
itemid=231873991
curl -sSb /tmp/cookies 'https://website.com' -H 'cookie: csrftoken=mytoken' -H 'x-csrftoken: mytoken' -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary' -H 'referer: https://website.com' \
  --data-binary $'------WebKitFormBoundary\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="shopid"\r\n\r\n${shopid}\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="itemid"\r\n\r\n${itemid}\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="quantity"\r\n\r\n1\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="donot_add_quantity"\r\n\r\nfalse\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="update_checkout_only"\r\n\r\nfalse\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="source"\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="checkout"\r\n\r\ntrue\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary--\r\n'
```

The `$''` quotes are necessary or else (ie. in the double-quoted case) `\r\n` won't work -- but with this form, `$shopid` and `$item` aren't replaced with their values.

How can I get both behaviors?

Comment: Take a look at: [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make that code maintainable

```
binary_data=$( cat <<END_DATA | sed 's/$/\r/'
------WebKitFormBoundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="shopid"

${shopid}
------WebKitFormBoundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="itemid"

${itemid}
------WebKitFormBoundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="quantity"

1
------WebKitFormBoundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="donot_add_quantity"

false
------WebKitFormBoundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="update_checkout_only"

false
------WebKitFormBoundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="source"


------WebKitFormBoundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="checkout"

true
------WebKitFormBoundary--
END_DATA
)

curl_opts=( 
    -sSb /tmp/cookies 
    -H 'cookie: csrftoken=mytoken' 
    -H 'x-csrftoken: mytoken' 
    -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary' 
    -H 'referer: https://website.com' 
    --data-binary "$binary_data"
)

curl "${curl_opts[@]}" 'https://website.com'
```

Comment: And maybe a little DRYer would be to put the boundary in a variable.

Comment: What do you mean by DRYer ?

Comment: DRY=Don't Repeat Yourself

Comment: Meaning you don't cut and paste code, you use functions to reuse it; you don't repeat literals, you define constant variables or similar.

Answer (score 1):

The variables are **not** expanded in 'single quotes'.

It's important to learn how quoting works :

> "Double quote" every literal that contains spaces/metacharacters and *every* expansion: `"$var"`, `"$(command "$var")"`, `"${array[@]}"`, `"a & b"`. Use `'single quotes'` for code or literal `$'s: 'Costs $5 US'`, `ssh host 'echo "$HOSTNAME"'`. See
>   http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes
>   http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments
>   http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words

---

So, try this :

```
data="------WebKitFormBoundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name='shopid'

${shopid}
------WebKitFormBoundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name='itemid'

${itemid}
------WebKitFormBoundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name='quantity'

1
------WebKitFormBoundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name='donot_add_quantity'

false
------WebKitFormBoundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name='update_checkout_only'

false
------WebKitFormBoundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name='source'


------WebKitFormBoundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name='checkout'

true
------WebKitFormBoundary--"

data="$(sed 's/$/\r/' <<< "$data")"

curl -sSb /tmp/cookies \
    -H 'cookie: csrftoken=mytoken' \
    -H 'x-csrftoken: mytoken' \
    -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary' \
    -H 'referer: https://website.com' \
    --data-binary "$data" \
    'https://website.com'
```

Comment: I just need to know how to make that curl command work, I know single quotes won't return variables but simply replacing single quotes with double quotes on that curl command won't solve the problem.

Comment: Because using double quotes also doesn't solve the problem

Comment: Thanks but I would put the post data in a variable just to make the curl command a bit shorter.

Comment: Take attention of the quoting way in the data to prevent conflict or the need to backslash/protect double quotes

Comment: I just tried your solution but it didn't work, it looks like you have to use sed just like the answer of glenn jackman above

Comment: In `sed 's/$/\r/'` may I know where you get the dollar sign from ? are you replacing the dollar signs from `${shopid}` and `${itemid}` ? and why are there three `<<<` I often only see 2 ?

Comment: The $ is an _anchor_ : it means _end of line_. `<<<` is a _here-string_ where `<<` is a _here-doc_ : Similar to here documents: The word after <<< and a newline are passed to the standard input of a command. Syntax: ''command <<< "some sentence"'' (Like ''echo "some sentence" | command'', but without the overhead of the subshell)

Comment: What is the difference between `<` and `<<<` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple quoting styles within a single string. Thus:

```
$'Constant\r\n\n\r\n'"$bar"
```

...has the `\r\n`s parsed with `$'...'` rules, but the `$bar` expanded with double-quoting rules (such that the expansion also takes place).